# How to iterate dynamically in an array in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have an array in my script which I want to use it in for, like this:

```
for j in "${list[@]}"
do
    func $j
done
```

In function func, **sometimes** another member will add to the list array, but the for iterates as many time as it was initiated(before the for started)
I want "for" to iterate based on the updated array content

some lines of that function:

```
if [ $s1 -gt 0 ]
then
   (( k = $k +1 ))
    list[$k]=$id2
fi
```

Comment: It is always pretty tricky to iterate over a list and modify the list at the same time.  I would definitely suggest trying to think if there is another way to accomplish what you're doing.  If this is the right approach for you though, you could probably find a way to use a `while` loop to keep the going and track where you are in the list, and possibly have it update the stop condition during iteration

Comment: given that your storing `$k` you could change the loop until $k instead of the in clause

Comment: Don't forget to quote `"$j"` on the line that passes it to `func`.  You don't want the shell treating the contents of the variable as code.  (word-splitting on whitespace)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Eric Renouf said, modifying the list you're working on can be tricky. As long as you're only appending new elements (to the **end** of the list), and just want those new elements included in the iteration, you can use something like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#list[@]}; i++)); do
    #...
    if (( s1 > 0 )); then
        list+=( "$id2" )
    fi
done
```

Since the length of the list (`${#list[@]}`) is recalculated every time around, the loop will include new elements. Also, the `+=( )` syntax guarantees you're always strictly appending.

Comment: You didn't specifically explain that `for` works by expanding the list to iterate over when it first runs, not once per iteration.  It's not iterating over the list per-se, it's iterating over that one expansion of `"${list[@]}"` which is done before the first loop iteration.  So it's not just the number of iterations, but also the values that `$j` will take, which are fixed.

Comment: @PeterCordes It never actually expands the entire list; `${#list[@]}` (note the `#`) is just the current length of the list, so the `for` loop runs until it gets to the (current) end of the list.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't talking about your code, I was talking about the other kind of for loop: `for var in "${list[@]}"`.  The way the OP phrased his description ("the for iterates as many time as it was initiated") made me want to point out what I did in my comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, in that case you're completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `k` is the index of the last element, meaning your function only appends items to the end of the list. It seems the best option is to iterate while a separate counter is less than `k`.

```
i=0
while (( i < k )); do
    j=${list[i]}
    func "$j"
    ((i++))
done
```